# spring data compose @query query dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have situation in which I have to compose a JPQL query in some method, then  pass this query to spring data query method to be used as the query in `@Query` annotation

```
@Query(value = ":DyanamicQuery")
List<PrizeInsuranceConfiguration> filterConfigurPrizeInsurance(String DyanamicQuery);
```

or at least the conditions part

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM PrizeInsuranceConfiguration c WHERE  :DyanamicConditions")
List<PrizeInsuranceConfiguration> filterConfigurPrizeInsurance(String DyanamicConditions);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do, you can do that. There are two reasons why not:

1. sql  injection (spring data work with prepared statements);
2. (result of first reasone) spring data create query tree and bind all params

But if you need dynamic query you can use [Specifications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/#specifications), [Query by Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/#query-by-example) or [Querydsl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl).