# How to add a dynamic where in @Query?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository, jpql

I need to add my where conditions based in my filter object. If some value in the filter object is null, isn't necessary add the where condition of this parameter.

How to add a dynamic where?

Exemple:

```
FilterObject{
  name: "Teste";
  age: null;
}

@Query(value="SELECT id FROM user WHERE name = FilterObject.name", nativeQuery = true)
public List<User> getUsers(???)
```

Other example:

```
FilterObject{
  name: "Teste";
  age: 12;
}

@Query(value="SELECT id FROM user WHERE name = FilterObject.name AND age = FilterObject.age", nativeQuery = true)
public List<User> getUsers(???)
```

This is a highlevel example. Isnt the correct code. But... Is the necessary to understand my question

If a parameter of my filter is null this parameter isnt used in my where

Im Using spring boot with Spring Data JPA and my Query stay in my repository a Repository.

My Original request:

```
    @Query(value = " SELECT "
        + " solicitacao.nm_orgao AS nmOrgao, "
        + " solicitacao.ds_ano_exercicio AS exercicio, "
        + " solicitacao.nm_organismo AS nmOrganismo, "
        + " dadosBancarios.valor AS valor, "
        + " dadosBancarios.valor * dadosBancarios.vl_taxa_cambio AS valorReais, "
        + " dadosFinanceiros.vl_dotacao_disponivel AS vlDotacaoDisponivel, "
        + " solicitacao.id_solicitacao AS codigoPagamento "
        + " solicitacao.tp_solicitacao_status AS  idFase, "
        + " organismo.id_orgao AS idOrgao, "
        + " solicitacao.id_organismo AS idOrganismo, "
        + " pagamentos.id_status_pagamento AS statusPagamento "
        + " FROM "
        + " tbs_solicitacao solicitacao "
        + " JOIN tbs_dados_bancarios dadosBancarios ON solicitacao.id_solicitacao = dadosBancarios.id_solicitacao "
        + " JOIN tbs_dados_financeiros dadosFinanceiros ON dadosFinanceiros.id_solicitacao = solicitacao.id_solicitacao "
        + " JOIN tbs_organismo organismo ON organismo.id_organismo = solicitacao.id_organismo "
        + " JOIN tbs_pagamentos pagamentos ON dadosFinanceiros.id_dados_financeiros = pagamentos.id_dados_financeiros ",nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> getRelatoriosProgramacao();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring data compose @query query dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995491/spring-data-compose-query-query-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data JPA specifications:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

You simply have to implement the method toPredicate:

```
 Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder);
```

In this method you get root, query and the CriteriaBuilder to create a Criteria API where predicate.

Event methods like findAll take a Specification.

Comment: I can use this in nativeQuery? And you can Show me a example?

Comment: Oh. No this will not work with nativeQuery. Why do you use native query?

Comment: because I need to join 2 tables.

Comment: I'm using in a query inside my repository. I will edit my Post to show you better

Comment: Maybe you should consider using jOOQ for these types of queries: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-jooq.html