# Spring data JPA - Dynamic SQL Execution

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I want to Execute the SQL , which will be constructed completely at runtime and it can be querying any tables in the schema.

Something like

```
@Repository public interface BaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Integer> {        
    @Query(":dynamicSQL")   
    List<Object> dynamicExecution(@Param("dynamicSQL") String dynamicSQL);           
}
```

Please suggest how this can be implemented

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring data compose @query query dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995491/spring-data-compose-query-query-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

JpaRepository is not designed to be used like this. If you want to execute dynamic SQL query then use EntityManager. This is bad design but if you still want to do this then use default methods and pass a EntityManager bean like this:

```
default List<?> dynamicExecution(EntityManager em, String sql) {
    return em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
}
```